# Connect AutoCAD Map 3D 2014 with MySQL

Tags: spatial-database, mysql, autocad-map

I need to connect AutoCAD Map 3D 2014 with an Spatial MySQL database (version 5.5) but first I have to install "**libmysql.dll**" to connect as specified in the software user's manual.

This file is currently inside MySQL 5.5 instalation folder. I've tried to register it using the typical regsvr32.exe step in comand line, both as Administrator and not. I've tried to put this file inside system32 and syswow64 folders (as I have W7 x64) and then tried to register again. I've tried to place the file inside the AutoCAD Map 3D 2014 folder (bin/FDO) and then register again.

Every time I get an error saying that the module was loaded but the DllRegisterServer was not found.
In the program's help it is specified that libmysql.dll must be installed before connecting but doesn't say **how** and **where**.

I know it's not the most used GIS but maybe someone had to deal with a similar problem using MySQL 5.5. Can someone specify it please?

Comment: You should have a C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Autodesk AutoCAD Map 3D 2014\FDO\bin (or similiar) Folder - place the  libmysql.dll  and register it there, a reboot is required.

Comment: Thank you but I've tried it yet. The path is bin\FDO. I can't get to register it because of the error "The module was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5c5ff4a-63d3-49ea-a20d-50ef45924b2e/dllregisterserver-entry-point-was-not-found?forum=vbinterop

Comment: Which would be the code you would enter in the cmd?

Comment: I isn't a .Net asembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this a week ago. The problem was that I had ACAD Map3D for 64bit and my mysql version was 32 bit so libmysql.dll was 32 bit too.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have to register the mysql dll. Instead, I just copy it into the bin/fdo dir.

I do not even have to reboot. I run a lab full of PCs and all I have to do is copy the dll into the folder and off we go.